# Unable to access Laravel Breeze app site using Valet URL

Tags: php, nginx, homebrew, laravel-valet

I have a Laravel Breeze (Vue3, Laravel 9, InertiaJS) site installed, and had it working fine with Valet, but after changing the project directory name, I have run into a myriad of problems just getting the site to even come up.

I had run `brew update`, and it upgraded the `php` version to the latest, which is 8.2, and Valet seemed to quit working. Doing some research, it seemed that Valet has issues with 8.2, so I uninstalled php and went back to 8.1 (the `php@8.1` formula). I even went so far as to uninstall/reinstall valet via composer, and also `dnsmasq` and `nginx` via homebrew.

However, with all that, I cannot get my Breeze site to come up with Valet. My site is installed at `~/Sites/laravel/members` and there are other sites under `/laravel`, so I ran `valet park` in `~/Sites/laravel`. That seems to have taken effect, because when I run `valet parked`, it shows my site

```
| Site      | SSL | URL                   | Path                                 |         |
+-----------+-----+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+---------+
| .idea     |     | http://.idea.test     | /Users/steve/Sites/laravel/.idea     | php@8.1 |
| members   |     | http://members.test   | /Users/steve/Sites/laravel/members   | php@8.1 |
+-----------+-----+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+---------+
```

Within my `.env`, I have `APP_URL=http://members.test`, and when I run `npm run dev` it starts vite just fine:

```
  VITE v3.2.4  ready in 931 ms

  ➜  Local:   http://localhost:5173/
  ➜  Network: use --host to expose

  LARAVEL v9.41.0  plugin v0.7.1

  ➜  APP_URL: http://members.test
```

However, accessing `http://members.test` just gives a `We can’t connect to the server at members.test.` error message, and if I go `localhost`, I get the Vite landing page.

The only things I can see are these: if I run `brew services list`. I get

```
Name              Status       User  File
mongodb-community started      steve ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist
mysql             started      steve ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
nginx             error  256   root  ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist
php@8.1           error  19968 root  ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.php@8.1.plist
redis             started      steve ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.redis.plist
```

and in my `php-fpm.log`, I get this:

```
[23-Dec-2022 15:13:49] NOTICE: [pool valet] 'user' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
[23-Dec-2022 15:13:49] NOTICE: [pool valet] 'user' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
[23-Dec-2022 15:13:49] NOTICE: [pool valet] 'group' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
[23-Dec-2022 15:13:49] NOTICE: [pool valet] 'group' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
[23-Dec-2022 15:13:49] ERROR: Another FPM instance seems to already listen on /Users/steve/.config/valet/valet81.sock
[23-Dec-2022 15:13:49] ERROR: Another FPM instance seems to already listen on /Users/steve/.config/valet/valet81.sock
```

There is only one version of PHP installed, so I'm not sure what other process would be listening.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Someone pointed that I had apparently competing `php-fpm` processes and that I  should let Valet take care of installing what it needs, so I

1. Uninstalled php@8.1 via homebrew
2. installed 8.2 (`brew install php`)
3. Ran `valet install`, which installed nginx and dnsmasq

and now it runs fine.